# How to hide the Back Button of UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, mono, xamarin.ios

I've tried various ways of hiding the back button of my `UINavigationController`

```
UINavigationController RVC = new UINavigationController();
other code
RVC.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true,true);
```

and other similar ways, but none of them have actually hidden the back button.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true,true);` within the controller you are pushing in the navigation controller. For example override `viewWillAppear` and put the code there.

Comment: Maybe I could answer your question..to have some points :-)

Comment: Smoore, I answered you question. Have a nice day.

Comment: I added a simple note. It could help you to understand something else. Cheers.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted You are very helpful and awesome <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true,true);` within the controller that it is pushed in the navigation controller. You could override `ViewWillAppear` and put the code there like:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated); 

    this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true,true);
}
```

Hope it helps.

*A simple note*

Since the navigation bar is unique for a `UINavigationController`, the button will maintains its state for all the controllers you push in the navigation controller. To explain the concept suppose you have two controllers, say A and B. You first push A and in its `ViewWillAppear` method you hide the button. When you push B, the button still remains not visible. If you want to unhide the button in B, you can play with its `ViewWillAppear` method (like before) and so on...

Comment: Or if you want to keep things contained to your one controller just set it back to false in ViewWillDisappear